# JSP not displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a JSP form that is retrieved using a RequestMapping during GET.
JSP page structure for the page looks like this:

```
<div id="myDiv">
     <script>
        function update() {
           update_fn(formId, ... more parameters);  // this is a function defined in a .js file, this submits the form
        }
     </script>

     <form:form ... >
        <button id="myButtonUniqueIDWithCurrentTime" onclick="update()">OK</button>
     </form:form>
</div>
```

Now when the button is clicked, udpate_fn() is called which sends a POST request using $.ajax. The RequestMapping contains the form annotated with `@ModelAttribute` and `@Valid`.

If BindResult is error free then I push the data to the database otherwise I send back the same form to the client. This is what it looks like.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/formSubmit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addData(
  @ModelAttribute("editForm") @Valid BackingForm form,
  BindingResult result, Model model) {

boolean success = false;
String message = "";
Map<String, Object> m = new HashMap<String, Object>();
if (form == null) {
  form = new BackingForm();
} else {
  if (result.hasErrors()) {
    success = false;
    message = "Please fix the errrors noted above";
  } else {
    try {
      MyEntity entity = form.getWrappedEntity();
      entityRepository.addData(entity);
      form = new BackingForm();    // why is empty form not visible in JSP
      success = true;
      message = "Data Successfully Added";
    } catch (EntityExistsException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
      success = false;
      message = "Entity Already exists.";
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
      success = false;
      message = "Internal Error. Please try again or report a Problem.";
    }
  }
}

m.put("editForm", form);
m.put("success", success);
m.put("message", message);

ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("editForm");
mv.addObject("model", m);

return mv;
```

}

This is the Javascript for the post request.

```
function updateGeneric(form, resultDivId, url) {
   var data = $("#" + form.getAttribute("id")).serialize();
   $.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : url,
    data : data,
    success : function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      $("#" + resultDivId).replaceWith(response);
    }
   });
}
```

As shown in the code above When the data is successfully added I do the following:

```
      form = new BackingForm();    // why is empty form not visible in JSP
      success = true;
      message = "Data Successfully Added";
```

Now when I putting this form in the ModelAndView and then replacing the rendered view with the ModelAndView returned'editForm.jsp', why is the correct form not showing up in the page?
I am getting the correct values for message, success in the jsp page.
But the form contains the values from the old submission even when it is set to a new form.

Note I am not redirecting after the POST. I am just replacing an HTML fragment using jquery.

Can you point out what is wrong with my code and what could be a neat way to do the same thing?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You're treating an AJAX request like it's Spring Form binding.  You should drop `@ModelAttribute` and `BindingResult` and create a slimmer API that uses something like Jackson to de-serialize an object passed from the front end as `@RequestBody` (rather than multipart data).  You can still user `@Valid` and something like `ResponseEntity` to return the proper error codes as HTTP data so the front end can display validation issues.

Comment: I was a bit uncomfortable with having an Ajax request use a ModelAttribute. But I don't know yet what is wrong with it. I am able to get the form data correctly. I can persist the data too. Can you show some code in an answer?

Comment: What version of Spring are you using?

Comment: Start with the information at #3 here: http://blog.goyello.com/2011/12/16/enhancements-spring-mvc31/

You'd also want to modify your JavaScript with an `error` callback that would behave appropriately.  This will also provide for cleaner separation between UI feedback branches.

Comment: Thanks I am having a look at it. If I understand correctly, you are suggesting that I am sending the form contents in the body of POST request, I should use this technique.
When should I use ModelAttribute then? Can I make ajax requests work with ModelAttribute?

What about ResponseBody? I was planning to send the whole form again as a response with the errors. The approach works and I get the errors inline using <form:errors/> tag.

I am not getting an empty form rendered on success. Even though I am doing backingform = new BackingForm(); and adding it to the model with the correct attribute.

Comment: This technique is more like a REST interface.  You should be transferring the form data as an object and keep the transfer as solely data (without the notion of a "form" existing beyond the front end).  `@ModelAttribute` wouldn't apply because you're just returning an object (which would be `@ReponseBody`) rather than a model. It sounds like the approach that you're working towards now is more like re-inventing JSF.  That is another option but I'd think you'd be better either using JSF itself or going closer to REST rather than trying to jam asynchrony where it's not expected.

Comment: How much effor to integrate JSF with spring ... lot of code rewrite? I doubt if I want to use JSF at this stage.

Comment: What I am doing right now is returning a ModelAndView which contains the jsp form and the model parameters like message, form (used to render jsp) Besides why do you think I am reinventing JSF?

Comment: JSF wouldn't be difficult to integrate.  I'd say you're in the direction of re-inventing it because you're starting down the path of trying to allow the backend to drive the intelligence for the UI layer, which JSF offers but the actual AJAX choreography will still be slimmer and more reactive.  In addition to transferring far more data per response with your approach, there's also far less flexibility in that the front end is not being created to handle any issues with the back-end and it will break in way that will confuse users.

Comment: If you have a simple enough use case and want to stick with what you have then the problem is likely that the `BindingResult` is still around and would be causing issues with Spring form binding.  You should be using a redirect, but otherwise you could try to clear out the binding result also.

Comment: How to clear BindingResult. I don't see a method to do that.
Also I don't want to spend time learning JSF given my deadlines and there is a lot of code I will have to refactor (https://github.com/C4G/V2V).
Previously I was returning a Map with ResponseBody annotation from the RequestMapping. I was not returning any view. Just a set of key value pairs that I parsed in Javascript. On success I was resetting the form using jquery. The reason I switched to view is that I want to show errors in the form using form:errors and I went down the path of rendering a new view all together.

Comment: I am considering switching back to @ResponseBody and returning the errors in the map itself. I can inject the errors in the appropriate tags by id using jquery. Do you see any problems here?

Comment: No, that sounds like a much cleaner approach

Comment: I will go with the ResponseBody approach then. I will keep this question open to see if someone can throw more light on it. If you have the time and can write an answer I will accept it. Thanks for your help.